# Is it necessary to show a visa required for the return ticket when entering Germany?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, international-travel, germany

I have a one way inbound ticket to Germany for a 2-week stay.
For my outbound ticket, I made a different reservation.

The thing is that my outbound ticket has a transit in UK and requires visa.
The question is: when entering in Germany, does anyone ask for the visa that you need for the UK, beside the retuning ticket?

It would help me a lot if you answer.

Comment: When entering the Schengen Area the Border Guards *can* check if you can return to your home country at the end if your intended stay. Article 6 (1)(c) *they justify the purpose and conditions of the intended stay, and they have sufficient means of subsistence, both for the duration of the intended stay and for the return to their country of origin or transit to a third country **into which they are certain to be admitted**, or are in a position to acquire such means lawfully;* It would be wise to get the required UK transit visa before entering the Schengen Area.

Comment: Id be concerned about what the airline flying you to Germany will do just as much as the Schengen immigration officers - the airline may want proof of a return ticket and the question of the visa may come up then.

Comment: What's your actual plan? If you do not have the visas necessary to use your flight home, that seems like a problem, and you probably want a UK visa (if your nationality requires one for airside transit) or a flight that does not transit the UK, regardless of what exactly would be checked in Germany. If your plan is to overstay your Schengen visa and not _use_ your flight home, well, you may or may not be able to get away with it, but it's a little outside the expertise of this site to be able to advise you exactly how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

No-one can tell you what they *will* do. But from my experience I can tell you that they definitely *can* ask to see it.

I traveled with a friend who had a passport that required a Schengen visa and a visa to the destination country, and we had a layover in a Schengen airport. When we decided to go out and see the city, they checked the Schengen visa (makes sense), but also checked the connection flight boarding pass **and checked the visa to the destination country**.